# Check all values in && comparison?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript is known to only check the first variable in a `&&` comparison in case the first variable returns false. Is there a way to 'ask' JavaScript to check both variables i.e. when they are methods?

For example: Suppose you have 2 methods that validate 2 separate user inputs:

```
const validateEmail = value => {
    if(value.contains('@')){
        setShowEmailError(false);
        return true;
    }
    setShowEmailError(true);
    return false;
};

const validatePswd = value => {
    if(value !== ''){
        setShowPswdError(false);
        return true;
    }
    setShowPswdError(true);
    return false;
};
```

Then check both conditions:

```
if(validateEmail(email) && validatePswd(pswd)){
    //validate entire form and render errors
}
```

However, the above will not execute the `validatePswd` method if the first method `validateEmail` returns false.

Is there a way to check if both values are true **and** run both methods? Having JavaScript run both methods would be a breeze in some cases.

Comment: Just call them ahead of time, store the return values in variables and use those variables in your conditional.

Comment: You can check both before the `if` and just use the result. But why checking anything with `if` would result in changing state?

Comment: @spender I was just wondering if you can do this without having to add more variables, like in C Sharp with a single `&`.

Comment: As @KonradLinkowski states, these validation functions should not have side effects. They should do one thing: decide if something validates. They can return their findings, and you can use that return value elsewhere to drive changes to the UI. In your particular case, you're making a very complicated version of `&&` that another developer (or you in 3 months time ) will look at and say "why didn't they just use `&&`? Let me fix that" with catastrophic consequences. Don't do surprising things in your functions. It's a maintenance hazard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute them in an array and then accumulate the result with `&&` by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function.

```js
const validateEmail = value => {
    if(value.includes('@')){
        //setShowEmailError(false);
        return true;
    }
    //setShowEmailError(true);
    console.log('wrong email')
    return false;
};

const validatePswd = value => {
    if(value !== ''){
        //setShowPswdError(false);
        return true;
    }
    // setShowPswdError(true);
    console.log('wrong password');
    return false;
};
// you can execute any number of validations within the array.
const result = [validateEmail('something'), validatePswd('')].reduce((acc, f) => acc && f, true);

console.log(result)
```

**UPDATE**

Or as @lux suggested using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method.

```js
const validateEmail = value => {
    if(value.includes('@')){
        //setShowEmailError(false);
        return true;
    }
    //setShowEmailError(true);
    console.log('wrong email')
    return false;
};

const validatePswd = value => {
    if(value !== ''){
        //setShowPswdError(false);
        return true;
    }
    // setShowPswdError(true);
    console.log('wrong password');
    return false;
};
// you can execute any number of validations within the array.
const result = [validateEmail('something'), validatePswd('')].every(r => r);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why not `every` on the array?

Comment: @lux, yes that will be better than reduce.

Comment: @lux, I update the answer witH suggestion too.

Comment: `every` ends execution on the first `false` found so not what OP wanted

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, yes, `every` ends execution on the first `false` but we already execute the methods in the array, `every` will just check if there is any validation with `false` to mark the input with `invalid` but all methods will be executed.

Comment: You are right, sorry :)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, never mind.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are looking for something like this:

```
const valEmail = validateEmail(email);
const valPsw = validatePswd(pswd);

if(valEmail && valPsw ){
    //validate entire form and render errors
}
```